# Assembly - Operand type mismatch for 'push'

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, x86-64, att

I am writing some assembly code using the `sys_connect` system call to connect to a listening socket on another machine. For this system call, I need to push the IP address to the stack in hexadecimal format. This is what I am currently doing:

```
connect:
    .......

    push        $0x8088A8C0                # The ip address in reverse order hexadecimal format
    pushw       $0x907e                 # Port in byte reverse order = 32400
    pushw       $2                          # AF_INET

    lea         (%rsp), %r11               # Struct pointer

    movq        $42, %rax
    movq        %r12, %rdi
    movq        %r11, %rsi
    movq        $16, %rdx
    syscall
```

The gcc compiler returns me this error:

```
Error: operand type mismatch for `push'
```

The error belongs to the line stating push `$0x8088A8C0`. How should I go about solving this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `pushd`?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError pushd gives me "no such instruction"> I however 'fixed' it by moving the hex to a register first and then pushing the register onto the stack.

Comment: You can't push that immediate because it's sign extended to 64 bits and the assembler thinks the resulting value is not what you want. If you only care about the low 32 bits you can convert it to a negative number -2138527552 and that will put `0xffffffff8088a8c0` on the stack.

Comment: @fuzl `pushl` is invalid in 64 bit mode.

Comment: @Jester I think converting it to a negative number would render the ip address invalid. Moving it into a register and then pushing the register to the stack would in this case be preferable

Comment: The ip address is in the low 32 bits so that should work I think.

Comment: @Jester That indeed works, thank you for that solution!

Comment: Actually you don't need to convert to decimal, you can just use `0xffffffff8088a8c0` directly and that should be somewhat more readable.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: In 64-bit mode, only `pushq` and `pushw` are encodeable, not `pushl` or "`pushd`".  You might think that a `REX.W=0` prefix could override the default operand size from 64 to 32, but that is unfortunately not the case.  [How many bytes does the push instruction push onto the stack when I don't specify the operand size?](//stackoverflow.com/q/45127993) goes into excruciating detail about this and push-immediate.  (One of my examples shows NASM warning about `push strict byte 0x80`, which is the same thing as this question if you already know the answer to this one.)